# Почему литерал типа double (подходящий для float) не авто-преобразовывается во float?

Tags: java, преобразование, преобразование-типов, syntax

Почему литерал типа double (подходящий для float) не авто-преобразовывается в float? **Но при этом, аналогичным образом, подходящий литерал int авто-преобразовывается в byte, short?**

```
    byte a = 1; // литарел типа int, к byte еденица подходит – всё работает
    float b = 1.0; // Ошибка: "Несоответствие типов: невозможно преобразовать double в float". Но ситуация аналогична команде выше!
```

Хотелось бы понять логику, соответствующую и первой и второй команде.

Answer (score 3):

По умолчанию, литерал 1.0 имеет тип double. Автоматически преобразовать тип double во float нельзя, потому-что может быть утрачена точность числа (точность типа float меньше, чем типа double). Следует явно указать преобразование типов для переменных. Для литералов можно указывать суффикс f или F, например:

```
    float b = 1.0f;
    float c = 1.0F;
    double d = 1.0;
    float e = (float) d;
    float f = (float) 1.0; // так тоже можно
    float f = dF; // так нельзя, суффикс F применим только к литералам
```

Comment: Это принцип с **"может быть"** не соответствует возможности авто-преобразования int в byte (здесь тоже может быть утрачено, само число).

Comment: Нет, никакого противоречия нет. Напишите byte b = 10000 и получите ошибку.  А вот с float/double все не так просто. Вы можете прописать два разных литерала, но положив их во float получите два одинаковых float. Потому и просят пользователя руками приводить double к float, чтоб разночтений не происходило